# Failed to access innerhtml elements in angular5

Tags: angular5

I am trying to access innerhtml elements in my component using it's id attribute.It works if I add the element directly into my template,but when I added the element through html binding I failed to access it in component.

**html**

```
<div [innerHtml]="testVal | safingHtml"></div>
```

**component**

```
testVal='<a id="up1">hello</a>';

ngAfterViewInit() {
    const elem=document.querySelector('#up1');
    console.log(elem); 
}
```

In the above code I am trying to access the html elelment after completing the initialization process.The code works if I added the elelment directly into the template otherwise it returns null.

I am also using custom pipe having 'DomSanitizer' to get the html attributes(id,style).

**custom pipe**

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {PipeTransform, Pipe} from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: 'safingHtml'})
export class SafingHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

is there anyway to access the innerhtml elements by using it's id apart from using 'viewchild' property  in angular5?